# How to get the admin page slug using wp_loaded hook?

Tags: ajax

For my plugin, I need to add this code line :

`add_action("wp_ajax_myfunction", array( "Namespace\ClassName","myfunction" ) );`

but I would like to load `myfunction` only for a specific admin page.

I cannot check `$_GET['page']` because `wp_ajax_[function_name]` can be added inside an action hook but before `parse_request` action, so `$_GET['page']` is undefined at this moment.

How can I idenfity my admin page before `parse_request` action using `wp_loaded` hook?

Comment: Do you need to use the `wp_loaded` hook or can you use a later one?

Comment: @Xhynk the next one is `parse_request` and `wp_ajax_[function_name]` does not work anymore with this action. [list of actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). It seems work only before using the HTTP request.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. AJAX requests are a separate request to the admin page, and don't load the admin page, so it makes no sense for `$_GET['page']` to be set.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie My question is not "How to use `$_GET['page']`  to set `wp_ajax_[function_name]` hook ?" . My question is "Is there a way to set the hook `wp_ajax_[function_name]` with a condition linked to the current page. For the moment, I have to set all `wp_ajax_[function_name]` even if I won't use one of these functions in the current page.